# How can I call from Angular App a function from Rust Smart Contract Solana?

Tags: anchor, web3.js, rust, typescript

I have this function in Rust Smart Contract Solana:

```
 pub fn buy_ticket(ctx: Context<BuyTicket>, lottery_id: u32) -> Result<()> {
        let lottery = &mut ctx.accounts.lottery;
        let ticket = &mut ctx.accounts.ticket;
        let buyer = &mut ctx.accounts.buyer;

        if lottery.winner_id.is_some() {
            return err!(LotteryError::WinnerAlreadyExists);
        }
        invoke(
            &transfer(&buyer.key(), &lottery.key(), lottery.ticket_price),
            &[
                buyer.to_account_info(),
                lottery.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            ],
        )?;

        lottery.last_ticket_id += 1;
        ticket.id = lottery.last_ticket_id;
        ticket.lottery_id = lottery_id;
        ticket.authority = buyer.key();

        msg!("Ticket id: {}", ticket.id);
        msg!("Ticket authority: {}", ticket.authority);

        Ok(())
    }
```

and this:

```
#[instruction(lottery_id:u32)]
pub struct BuyTicket<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [LOTTERY_SEED.as_bytes(), &lottery_id.to_le_bytes()],
        bump
    )]
    pub lottery: Account<'info, Lottery>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = buyer,
        space = 4 + 4 + 32 + 8,
        seeds = [
            TICKET_SEED.as_bytes(),
            lottery.key().as_ref(),
            &(lottery.last_ticket_id + 1).to_le_bytes()
        ],
        bump
    )]
    pub ticket: Account<'info, Ticket>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub buyer: Signer<'info>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Ticket {
    pub id: u32,
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub lottery_id: u32,
}
```

I builded and deployed to https://beta.solpg.io and I have one lottery active:

```
[{
    "publicKey": "6WwWbKYf7BzwZLWZdibeYqeixXvZdxSmc5qcDdKq44AG",
    "account": {
      "id": 1,
      "authority": "GeanNrzhjbvqSZmmVxtdE2cD4dc3mVpk2XyHhRUstrkQ",
      "ticketPrice": "1000000000",
      "lastTicketId": 2,
      "winnerId": 1,
      "claimed": false,
      "timestamp": "1707683900"
    }
}]
```

If I try to buyTicket from the https://beta.solpg.io calling the buyTicket function with args -> lotteryId: u32 = 1, accounts -> lottery: publicKey = 6WwWbKYf7BzwZLWZdibeYqeixXvZdxSmc5qcDdKq44AG, ticket generated from seeds:
. seed(1): string = 'ticket'
. seed(2): publicKey = 6WwWbKYf7BzwZLWZdibeYqeixXvZdxSmc5qcDdKq44AG
. seed(3): u32 = 1
. seed(4): publicKey = Program ID (I don't put the original value)
, buyer: publicKey = GeanNrzhjbvqSZmmVxtdE2cD4dc3mVpk2XyHhRUstrkQ and systemProgram: publicKey = Program ID (I don't put the original value). **It works**.

In Angular App I have this function and inside it I tried to create the ticket: publicKey from seed with that 4 seeds as before and after that to call the buyTicket function with the exactly same values as before:

```
async buyTicket(
    lotteryId: string,
    lotteryPublicKeyString: string,
    buyerPublicKeyString: string,
    last_ticket_id: string
  ) {
    const ticketSeed = Buffer.concat([
      Buffer.from(TICKET_SEED),
      new PublicKey(lotteryPublicKeyString).toBuffer(),
      Buffer.from(last_ticket_id),
      PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
    ]);
    const ticketPublicKey = new PublicKey(sha256(ticketSeed)).toString();
    const lotteryPublicKey = new PublicKey(lotteryPublicKeyString);
    const buyerPublicKey = new PublicKey(buyerPublicKeyString);
    try {
      await this.program.rpc['buyTicket'](lotteryId, {
        accounts: {
          lotteryPublicKey,
          ticketPublicKey,
          buyerPublicKey,
          PROGRAM_ID,
        },
        signers: [],
      });
      console.log('Ticket bought successfully!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error buying ticket:', error);
    }
  }
```

When I call it I receive this error:

```
data.service.ts:157 Error buying ticket: Error: Invalid arguments: lottery not provided.
    at index.js:133:23
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at validateAccounts (index.js:127:16)
    at ix (index.js:4873:13)
    at txFn (index.js:4964:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:4937:24)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:27:1
```

Can you help me to create this buyFunction to works as at https://beta.solpg.io? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Notice your account names. Your instruction requires `lottery`, `ticket`, `buyer`, `systemProgram`. In your Angular code, you are passing these accounts, but the names are not right.

Specifically, notice this part of your code:

```
await this.program.rpc['buyTicket'](lotteryId, {
  accounts: {
    lotteryPublicKey,
    ticketPublicKey,
    buyerPublicKey,
    PROGRAM_ID,
  },
  signers: [],
});
```

The keys of the object `accounts` are `lotteryPublicKey`, `ticketPublicKey`, `buyerPublicKey`, `PROGRAM_ID` as you have not explicitly added keys, these values end being key names with the variable value being the respective key's value. Update it to this:

```
await this.program.rpc['buyTicket'](lotteryId, {
  accounts: {
    lottery: lotteryPublicKey,
    ticket: ticketPublicKey,
    buyer: buyerPublicKey,
    systemProgram: PROGRAM_ID,
  },
  signers: [],
});
```